# FontAwesome icons in the AppBar of Windows 10 Universal Apps

Tags: html, css, windows-store-apps, font-awesome, appbar

I'm trying to set a custom icon for my Universal app's appbar. Segoe UI Symbol just doesn't have everything I'm after. I would like to use FontAwesome.  Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to do that.

The only official way I can find to put custom icons into an app bar is to use PNGs, but these do not scale as well as font-awesome and are awkward to make.

The closest I've come is to create a div based element on the appbar which looks like an appbar button:

```
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" 
    data-win-options="{ id:'btnLab',label:'Lab', section:'global', type:'content'}">
    <div id="itemContainer" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ItemContainer">
        <i class="fa fa-flask" style="color: #000; font-size: 19px; 
           padding: 10px; border: 2px solid #222; border-radius: 50%;">
        </i>
        <br/>
        <span style="color: #000; font-size: 12px;">Lab</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This produces something pretty close to an appbar button, which is clickable and can be assigned a behaviour

[image]

With some tweaking I believe I could get this to look identical to a button, however I'm not confident it will scale the same way that normal app bar buttons do. Also when hovering there is this nasty border around it:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can just use font-awesome, or some other font based icon set, directly in a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer for this - it can be done quite easily using script. I used the DOM inspector to find that the actual HTML for the button image is like so

```
<button class="win-disposable win-command win-global" id="cmdKey" role="menuitem" 
  aria-label="Key" type="button" data-win-options="{id:'cmdKey',label:'Key',icon:'',
  section:'global',tooltip:'testing out font-awesome'}" 
  data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand">
    <span tabindex="-1" class="win-commandicon win-commandring" 
     aria-hidden="true">
         <span tabindex="-1" class="win-commandimage" aria-hidden="true" 
          style="-ms-high-contrast-adjust: none;"></span>
    </span>
    <span tabindex="-1" class="win-label" aria-hidden="true">
         Key
    </span>
</button>
```

You can very easily target `win-commandimage` using either jQuery or straight JS and put a font-awesome icon directly in there

```
$('#cmdKey .win-commandimage').html('<i class="fa fa-key"></i>');
```

I find the icons a little small, but this can easily be fixed with CSS

```
#cmdKey .win-commandimage
{
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue yesterday.

```
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar" id="appBar" data-win-options="{placement: 'bottom'}" style="overflow: hidden;">       
         <button class="fa fa-flask" style="font-size: 2em; padding-bottom: 15px;" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{id: 'flaskBtn', section:'global', label: 'Lab', tooltip:'Lab'}"></button>         
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var myAppBar = element.querySelector("#appBar");
myAppBar.winControl.closedDisplayMode = "full";
```

This worked for me. To enlarge the font size, I had to use **style="font-size: 2em"** -- for some reason, the larger icon classes (fa-lg, fa-2x, fa-3x, fa-4x) don't work when declared in a class and it's within an AppBar.

**class="fa fa-flask fa-2x"** works if you create a Font Awesome element outside of an AppBar.

Comment: not working for me I'm afraid - the button is blank?

Comment: Have you linked to the stylesheet? <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome.css" />

Comment: yes, I'm using fontawesome in other places in default.html so that's definitely not the issue

Comment: made some progress. If I remove your `font-size` style the icon and label now appear, with the icon very small and off to the left. If I gradually increase the font-size it affects the label size too.

Comment: Glad the icon works for you now. I started a blank project aimed at just getting the app bar working with Font Awesome, so it's strange that the style didn't work for you.

Comment: the icon appears, but I can't increase the font size without affecting the label. All the fa-2x class does is increase the font-size itself. The icon is still off to the left, well outside the button circle